# Tomcat 301 redirect X-Frame-Options

Tags: tomcat

I have a couple tomcat web servers that have a 80->443 redirect. The redirect is not passing  X-Frame-Options, but the SSL site is. I understand that it's not critical for security to pass that on the 301, but our external scans are complaining about it. Is there a configuration option to turn them on for the redirect?

I've got this or similar on the sites.

httpHeaderSecurity
    org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter
    
        antiClickJackingOption
        SAMEORIGIN

to ensure that they are set to same origin. It does not get passed on the 301